# WPF Intercepting/Routing Events

Tags: wpf, routed-events

I have a question concerning event handling/routing in WPF. Specifically, I have an application with the following design:

[image]

Where view1/viewmodel1 is the root node for views/viewmodels 2 & 3.

Now my problem is how to route a mouse event from view2/viewmodel2 TO view3/viewmodel3?

I can bubble an event up to view1/viewmodel1.

I can tunnel from view1/viewmodel1 -> view2/viewmodel2.

But I am lost on how to route an event from 2 -> to 3.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

//N

Comment: You're looking for an "event aggregator" - see this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42302588/how-do-i-communicate-events-between-viewmodels-in-a-net-wpf-mvvm-application.

Comment: Another more naive way to do it would be to bubble up to View1 then tunnel it back down to View3 again - but that feels like it breaks MVVM

Comment: Thanks I'll look into the event aggregator. However, regarding your second suggestion, Im a little unclear how I would tunnel it back down to v3/vm3.

For example: A MouseDown event in v2/vm2 would bubble up to v1/vm1, how could i then "tunnel" that event down to v3/vm3?

Comment: I'm assuming that v1/vm1 hold references to 2 and 3? If so you could just call a method directly.